# how to return json object from jquery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to return a JSON object from jQuery but i get the following error:

```
VM93:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1.
```

The following is my code:

```
<?php
  $soapclient = new SoapClient();
  $params = array("id" => "31");
  $response = $soapclient->GetMovieById($params);
  echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mylittleweewee").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "soap.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                var json = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(json);
            }
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please correct your post to get the code right?

Comment: Okay, so what's getting in the console for you?

Comment: Object {GetMovieByIdResult: Object}GetMovieByIdResult: Object__proto__: Object
VM94:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 I get this error message in the console

Comment: Boss, that doesn't look like JSON. That's the problem...

Comment: its based on soap request for xml

Comment: Is it possible to convert it into a proper JSON? I don't think so. Can you please put the full code?

Comment: Show us the code for this function: `GetMovieById`.

Comment: If you're just getting JSON, you don't need the whole `$.ajax` ceremony. Just use `$.getJSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are specifying `dataType: "json"`, jQuery already performs the JSON decoding for you, so your `response` is already an object. You should remove this line:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
```

... and work with `response` as an object.

Answer (score 0):

response should be a text in the order to use `JSON.parse` 
in my opinion just move   `dataType: "json"` to   `dataType: "html"`

Comment: You're right about it, but the server return JSON, and not HTML:  `echo json_encode($response);` so I think the OP need to remove `var json = JSON.parse(response);`